# LinkedList Operation Cost

Tags: data-structures, linked-list, big-o

What is the cost of finding an element in a linked list?  I know that the cost of finding an element in a balanced binary search tree which is O(log n), but what about a linked list?

Answer (score 2):

If you know nothing about the elements in the linked list and have no pointers into the list, the cost of searching for an element in a linked list is O(1) in the best case and O(n) in the worst-case.  In the best case, you find the element at the very front, and in the worst case have to look at all elements before deciding that the element you're searching for isn't there.

This is much slower than a balanced binary search tree in the worst-case, so there are some variations on the linked list designed to speed up access.  The [skip list](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skip_list), for example, uses multiple parallel linked lists to make it possible to "skip" over elements in the list.  This requires the elements to be stored in sorted order, but it does decrease the lookup time to expected O(log n).

Hope this helps!

Comment: yeah i got it,it means that if my list is full or has some elements the operation will cost me O(n) to find a particular element in the list am i right ?

Comment: @user1895448- Usually linked lists aren't "full" or "empty."  But yes, you should expect to spend linear time searching a linked list for a particular element.

Comment: This O(1) doesn't make sense, that's not how big-O notation works. You have to look in average, and in average you traverse n/2, so the complexity is O(n) since constants are factored out. Saying in the best case it's O(1) is just plain wrong. My point is that you can speak about the best case and say it takes one operation, but not that it's O(1)

Comment: You can use big-O notation to describe the growth rates of different quantities as a function of some variable. As a function of the length n of a linked list of n elements, the best-case cost of a search is O(1) because it doesn’t scale as a function of the list length. You can alternatively use big-O notation to describe the average-case cost of a search, which would be O(n) because it scales linearly with the length of the list.